# Why can't the linker find the CppUnit libraries?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to learn the CPPUNIT i looked at the following link:

[CPPUNIT](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html)

although the selected language here is c i have selected c++ while creating this application and have added the

C:\cppunit\cppunit-1.12.1\include to the include directories i have also added cppunitd,cppunit in the linker options however i still the errors as while i try to test the cppunit.

Errors:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find    
-lcppunitd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcppunit
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcppunit
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/tests/TestFiles/f1] Error 1
make: *** [.build-tests-impl] Error 2


BUILD TESTS FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

Comment: Ed's answer below is probably correct, but you might want to post your Makefile or at least the relevant gcc command lines that are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the `-L` flag and have a path to the library.

Comment: u mean using lcppunit in the linker library options and i could not locate cppunit in the include options of the librry

Comment: Yes - Give the compiler/linker a help in that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same linker error and found that I only had 64-bit version of CppUnit installed while building 32-bit application. I solved it by installing 32-bit version of the library.